# How do I use command blocks to teleport multiple random players to specific spots?

Tags: minecraft-commands

I've never dabbled in command blocks before, but I'm slowly learning. I am making a murder mystery mini game. I have a ton of problems but the one I am stuck on now is I want to teleport all the remaining alive players to a table, and around the table all facing the center. I don't want to teleport anyone who has died, and I have barely learned how to use @a for all to a singular spot.

Comment: Are you using Bedrock Edition or Java Edition?  I'm pretty sure that the commands would be the same for both in this instance, but there are still different edge cases.

Comment: Voting to close because you have not mentioned version. Please specify the version for a retract/reopen.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you are using Java Edition and are playing in version 1.13 or later. I am also going to assume the "dead" players are spectators.

```
tag @a[gamemode=!spectator] add unteleported                  //Give the "unteleported" tag to all players not in spectator mode
```

Run these 2 commands before each table meeting.

---

```
tag @a[tag=unteleported,limit=1,sort=random] add teleporting  //Give the "teleporting" tag to one random unteleported player
tp @a[tag=teleporting,limit=1] <seat1> facing 12 65 12        //Teleport the player with the "teleporting" tag to the 1st 'seat' around the table (10 64 10), facing the center of the table
tag @a[tag=teleporting,limit=1] remove unteleported           //Remove the "unteleported" tag from all players with tag "teleporting"
tag @a[tag=teleporting,limit=1] remove teleporting            //Remove the "teleporting" tag from all players with tag "teleporting"
```

Repeat this second section for all <seat> coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

I built a meeting table like so:
[image]

Next I built this structure high in the sky, directly above the meeting table. I made sure no blocks were above it:
[image]

Then, I took the `x` and `z` coordinates of the center of the meeting table and put it into the `/spreadplayers` command to get:
`/spreadplayers -24.50 -19.50 1 2 false @a[gamemode=!spectator]`

Then: `/execute as @a[gamemode=!spectator] at @s run tp @s ~ ~-24 ~ facing -24.50 57.5 -19.50`

Done!

### How does it work?

---

`/spreadplayers` will teleport the selected targets randomly around an area. It will avoid water/lava, among other things. That is why the stone structure in the water is actually an outline of the meeting table. Each block represents a spot where the players could teleport to.

The spreadplayers command actually spreads the players onto this structure, and then I just teleport the players downwards and facing the center of the table.

The syntax of `/spreadplayers` is:

`spreadplayers <center> <spreadDistance> <maxRange> <respectTeams> <targets>`

You can begin to see why my `/spreadplayers` command looks the way it does:

```
center = -24.50 -19.50             //The center of the meeting table (and the stone structure)
spreadDistance = 1 block           //I want the players to be spread at least 1 block apart
maxRange = 2 blocks                //I want the spreadplayers command to try to spread players within 2 blocks.
respectTeams = false               //Since I'm not using teams, I don't care about keeping them together
targets = @a[gamemode=!spectator]  //I don't want to teleport dead players
```

Answer (score -1):

to do this. you cant do it with ONE command block, you need to have as many random players as you want. or you do /spreadplayers or you choose about 50 different locations and put it in 50 command blocks. then you do     [tp @r X Y Z].